# Angular2 Runtime Loaded Components

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular2-template

I have quite a specific requirement and it's proving difficult to invasion how I would go about doing this. If anyone has any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

My goal is to allow a backend server to install an NPM module containing an Angular2 component at runtime. When a user visits the frontend page where the component exists the backend would stream the component through a Websocket/REST api and display it in the browser.

The main challenge here is the issue that Angular2/Webpack bundles all the content up and makes it difficult to make any changes at runtime. I've looked at dynamic components but they seem to require a component in the first place to get use.

One of my current ideas is to create an XML set of pre-made interface elements which can be reproduced by a recursive Angular2 component and ngSwitch statement but I'm doubt it's the best solution.

Thanks,
Victor